How to fix the error message : "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :" in R?
I am trying to perform an simple ordinal logistic regression in R.
I have loaded these libraries :
library(ordinal)
library(readxl)
library(rcompanion)
library(foreign)
library(ggeffects)
library(ggiraph)
library(predict3d)

Here are the codes that I typed so far :
data <- read_excel("C:/Users/*****/OneDrive/Documents/Applied Econometrics/AppEcon/DATA/Adult.Dataset.xlsx")
data

data$INCOME_GREATER_THAN_50K_CODE <- factor(data$INCOME_GREATER_THAN_50K_CODE, ordered=TRUE)

model_clm1 <- clm(INCOME_GREATER_THAN_50K_CODE ~ EDUCATION_CODE, data = data)
summary(model_clm1)

nagelkerke(model_clm1)
AIC(model_clm1)
BIC(model_clm1)

ggpredict(model_clm1, terms = "EDUCATION_CODE[5,10,13]")

I restarted my R session and installed these packages :
library(ggeffects)
library(ggiraph)
library(predict3d)

However, when I typed ggpredict(model_clm1, terms = "EDUCATION_CODE[5,10,13]"), this is the error message that prompts :
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'diag': "crossprod" is not a BUILTIN function

My desired output when I type ggpredict(model_clm1, terms = "EDUCATION_CODE[5,10,13]") is this :


First, do you have a reproducible example? Else, I guess it's very difficult to find a solution. Second, after you get the error, please run traceback() and post the output here. That might help.
